# How to install ILMerge on 64 bit Windows7

Tags: ilmerge

Running the ILMerge.msi (version 2.12.0803) on my 64 bit Windows 7 SP1 machine with .NET 4.0 fails & puts up an error dialog reading "This setup requires the .NET Framework version .  Please install the .NET Framework and run this setup again."  The ILMerge page at Microsoft Research says it should work with .NET 4.0 and Windows 7 but is silent about 64 bit.  Has anyone installed it on 64 bit Windows?

Comment: I presume you also have the .net 2.0 runtime installed?

Answer (score 2):

Installing via [nuget](https://nuget.org/packages/ilmerge) indeed did the trick for me. Note that I do not have the .NET 2 Framework installed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing via the [nuget package](https://nuget.org/packages/ilmerge)? If that also fails, it might pay to contact [Mike Barnett](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/default.aspx) and he'll get you sorted.